# id is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Каждому подключенному модулю задан id с соответствующим именем. При нажатии на ссылку нужно узнавать id этой ссылки, и загружать модуль с названием id. Выдает ошибку что идентификатор не определен

```
const showContent = require('./modules/showContent');
const main = require('./modules/screens/main');
const about = require('./modules/screens/about');
const blog = require('./modules/screens/blog');
const contacts = require('./modules/screens/contacts');
const gallery = require('./modules/screens/gallery');

$(document).ready(function() {
  showContent(main);
    $(document).on("click", "a", (e) => {
        if ( $(this).hasClass('active') ) return;

        $("a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $(".slide").slideUp(800);

        showContent(this.id);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function(e) {
  ...
```

У стрелочной функции `this` - из внешнего блока, очевидно - `document`.